# MySQL - very complicated random row

Tags: mysql, join, random

I've got my tables `posts` and `user_unread_posts`.
In `posts`, all the posts of a forum are saved, and in `user_unread_posts` all posts are saved which are read by a user.

`user_undread_posts`looks like this:

```
id   uid   pid
```

Now I want to allow users to open a random post which they haven't read. I've tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN user_unread_posts uup
ON uup.pid=posts.id
WHERE uup.uid<>1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

(Whilst 1 is a placeholder UID)

But it doesn't work, like it should work, it return posts too, which are read... How can I fix that?

Comment: FROM posts INNER JOIN user_unread_posts  ?

Comment: Do I undestand right: you are storing read posts in a table called "unread posts"?

Comment: No, yes: This was an example, the real table names aren't like this. Stupid me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    posts
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  pid
        FROM    user_unread_posts uup
        WHERE   uid = $myuserid
        )
ORDER BY
        RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to use IS NULL with the LEFT JOIN.  Using <> turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN because NULL can never match the <> operator.

Here is a corrected query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN user_unread_posts uup
ON uup.pid=posts.id
WHERE uup.uid IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```